# How to replicate the configuration of a self-signed certificate with OpenSSL?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have a load balancer that requires a certificate with a specific configuration, unfortunately those who created the first certificates did not document this configuration and I only have a list of commands that is not complete either.

I have these two files: **example_ca.crt** and **example.crt**

And using this OpenSSL command:

```
openssl x509 -in file_name.crt -text -noout
```

These are its properties (I will omit non-relevant information):

**example_ca.crt**

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            cb:0f:b8:78:38:9a:a9:da
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN = example.org
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun 10 10:33:06 2020 GMT
            Not After : May 17 10:33:06 2120 GMT
        Subject: CN = example.org
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    [...]
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                81:FE:D0:6D:DE:0A:CC:10:1D:B3:74:EA:4B:C8:F3:43:37:B4:D1:FD
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:81:FE:D0:6D:DE:0A:CC:10:1D:B3:74:EA:4B:C8:F3:43:37:B4:D1:FD

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         [...]
```

**example.crt**

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            80:1d:bb:9e:9f:2c:4e:ce
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN = example.org
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun 10 10:33:44 2020 GMT
            Not After : May 17 10:33:44 2120 GMT
        Subject: CN = example.org
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    [...]
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Client Authentication, TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:81:FE:D0:6D:DE:0A:CC:10:1D:B3:74:EA:4B:C8:F3:43:37:B4:D1:FD

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                B1:2C:74:04:EE:03:84:C9:F7:92:35:CE:6E:20:EF:C6:FE:B8:23:A7
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         [...]
```

I managed to replicate **example_ca.crt** with these commands and configuration (the expiration date is not relevant):

```
openssl genrsa -out example_ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key example_ca.key -out example_ca.crt -config root.cnf
```

**root.cnf**

```
# OpenSSL configuration for Root CA

[ req ]

prompt             = no
string_mask        = default

default_bits       = 2048
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
x509_extensions    = x509_ext

[ req_distinguished_name ]
commonName = example.org

[ x509_ext ]
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth, serverAuth
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid
basicConstraints=CA:true
```

My problem comes at this point when I can't replicate **example.crt**, I have tried so many possibilities in the **server.cnf** and **openssl.cnf** file and I don't get any closer to the desired result.

For the last steps I have used these commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out example.key 2048
openssl req -new -out example.csr -key example.key -config server.cnf

echo extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth > openssl.cnf
openssl x509 -req -in example.csr -out example.crt -signkey example.key -CA example_ca.crt -CAkey example_ca.key -CAcreateserial -days 365 -extfile openssl.cnf
```

I will skip the contents of **server.cnf** because that is where I need help. But basically I always miss the **"X509v3 extensions"** session of **example.crt**

Feel free to force the use of a password if necessary, or to correct my replication of **example_ca.crt** I have simply explained the fundamentals.

**UPDATE:**

**server.cnf**

```
# OpenSSL configuration for end-entity cert

[ req ]
prompt             = no
string_mask        = default

default_bits       = 2048
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name

x509_extensions    = x509_ext

[ req_distinguished_name ]
commonName = example.org

[ x509_ext ]
keyUsage=critical,digitalSignature,keyAgreement

subjectAltName = @alt_names

Multiple Alternate Names are possible
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = example.org
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
# DNS.2 = altName.example.com
```

Comment: It would be easier for people to help you with `server.cnf` if you showed yours within your question.

Comment: Don't use `-signkey` together with `-CA -CAkey` -- they cannot both be effected on the same cert, but instead of an error this apparently causes the extensions to be duplicated(!!) and possibly mangled as well

Comment: ALSO: if you're really using the names shown, you have `CN=example.org` for **both** the CA and the server; this won't work when you try to use the cert for anything. They must be different. For HTTPS (I assume the load balancer is HTTPS) the CN must be the domainname when SAN is not present (which would be better practice but you don't have); the CA name need not be a domainname (and need not even be CN; you could use O, OU, and more).

Comment: Thank you very much!, I was able to solve everything, the CN is not definitive, it is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `local.cnf` file with something similar to (remove my comments if you want):

```
[server]

# These two are expected...
subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid:always,issuer

# This is wise for end-entities and SHOULD be critical:
# keyUsage = critical, digitalSignature, keyAgreement
# Choose (wisely) from: digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment, keyAgreement,  encipherOnly, and decipherOnly
# but not keyCertSign or cRLSign as they are for CAs.

# This is for end-entity certificates only.
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth, serverAuth
# Choose (wisely) from: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/x509v3_config.html#Extended-Key-Usage
```

Then, use the following flags on your `openssl x509` command to apply:

```
openssl x509 ... -extfile local.cnf -extensions server
```

Comment: I have done what you said but two details, the order of the "subjectKeyIdentifier" and "authorityKeyIdentifier" are different in each .crt file, following your instructions the order is the same for both files. On the other hand also the values of "extendedKeyUsage" are repeated twice, I have updated the question so you can see the content of server.cnf but I really don't trust that I did it right.

Comment: Your first part is wrong; if `x509 -req` has `-extfile` but not `-extensions` it either uses the value of `extensions` from the default section (which OP didn't have) or else the default section itself (which OP did have). But you're right on the values that should be _in_ the section used, whatever it is. @Willy: to prevent the duplicated extensions, remove `-signkey` as I commented on the Q.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - thanks.  I've fixed it.  Every day's a school day :-)